# iOS Making a custom table view with spaced out and custom cells

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

[image]

I am attempting to make a custom view that looks like the attached picture. The top two cell would be static while the bottom three would scroll if there are more than the screen can fit, and only scroll within that given area. I am wondering what the best approach is to making these types of custom views. I know how to make custom UItableviewcells and have custom content in them, but I am struggling with an overall strategy to make a custom UITableview that has certain cells be static and others scroll. Should I just implement a table view to be part of the screen in storyboards? Or are there better ways to do so?

Comment: Put the two top cells directly on the page as its subviews. They would be siblings of the table view. The rest of the table view would be normal. If you style your top cells properly, end-users would have hard time figuring out that these cells are not part of the table.

Comment: Why use a table view? Why not just have a regular view controller with some static views? Use a scroll view for the lower portion. You don't say if you need the 5 "cells" to work like regular table view cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this by making the top two "cells" just be UILabels, and the bottom a table view where both the cells and the table view would have a clear background. The table view should be set to have no separators between the cells, and the cells should have a UILabel with a background cooler the same as the top UILabels.

[image]

This was the result:

[image]

Comment: What if instead of a label, I want the cells that are numbered One Two Three to be of type UiTableViewCell, but still be spaced as you have shown in the last image. The reason I ask is because I need to put more than just plain text into those cells.

Comment: @user1933131, One way to do that, would be to make each one of those cells a separate section, and add clear headers or footers to each section. Another way would be to make every other cell have no content and a clear background.

Answer (score 0):

I normally do not like to use story board much. And prefer SubClassing UIView. It might take more time to code at first but in a long run it is easier and very dynamic to control the UI programmatically.

In your problem I would make two static UIView(s). If the two view are similar the advantage of using UIView class is that you can use same class with different data model to generate multiple views. But if you use story board you need to copy past multiple times. Hence try to create UIViews class objects as much as possible.

And then the bottom one will be a simple table view. Do not think there is much you can do in this case. Do submit some codes you have done so that we can better refine it.

Comment: I have a simple code uploaded to Github https://github.com/bishalg/SliderMenu which you can learn from where I have used same view multiple times.